# How to tell TeamCity to treat merges as a single commit when working with git?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, teamcity

We recently moved from SVN to git. We work with a main "release" branch (master), and feature branches for every feature a dev is working on. 
In [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) we have a project for every feature branch, and of course a project for the master.

When we worked with SVN, whenever someone merged from master to his feature branch or vice-versa, the merge was treated by TeamCity as one commit. Now, with git, every merge causes TeamCity to show all of the commits that came with this merge.

This causes some problems, for example when someone merge from master to his feature branch, and now his TeamCity project shows "283 pending changes" due to that merge, if builds fail, the authors of these changes will be notified, as if they did these changes on the feature branch.

Is there a way to tell TeamCity to treat git merges as single commit?

We could solve it using squashed merges but that's something we would really like to avoid.

Comment: Can you just use `git rebase`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. We push our commits to a central repo, the one team city is listening to. We can't really rebase pushed changes, right? we kinda have to use merging.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid squashed merges?

Comment: Squashed merges aren't really merges, it will give us headaches like solving the same conflicts over and over again each time we try to (squash) merge from/to master. Am I right?

Comment: Yes – don’t do squashed merges.

Comment: Btw: From the way you worded your question, I assume that you have some misunderstanding about how git works. A merge is only one commit in git, but by merging all the commits that got merged become part of the feature branch. What you are looking for is not “all the commits in the feature branch” (`git log feature`), but “all the commits in the feature branch that are not part of master” (`git log feature ^master`). I wonder how TeamCity gets that specific set of 283 changes – that’s something that’s actually rather hard to get from git.

Comment: I knew that about merges :)
That log command seems promising, the question is if you can somehow tell TeamCity to query the changes using it.

Comment: Rebase followed by squash is the way it's done at big software houses to keep the history clean. Nobody on the main branch should need to care about all of the little commits that happened on someone's feature branch.

Comment: but... it's impossible to rebase commits that are already pushed, right?

Comment: you can do a force update on remote when you rebase .. of course it has it's own set of problems :)

Comment: What you might actually want is to be able to (somehow) notify the 'owner' of a branch, and not the committers. This is a feature I would also like to see in TeamCity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two possible solutions:

1. One way to solve this (though possibly very awkward, depending on your situation) is to notify users on the level of a build configuration as opposed to notifying who committed/was merged. Create separate build configurations for different topic branches and configure notification per build configuration so that only the 'owner' of the topic branch is notified.
2. Less sure, but worth a try: You could configure notification per topic branch(es), e.g. by wildcard patterns on the branch path. This should be possible by means of a DYI *custom notifier plug-in* that uses e.g. the branch name property,  [teamcity.build.vcs.branch.<my_vcs_name>](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/What%27s+New+in+TeamCity+7.1#What%27sNewinTeamCity7.1-VCSbranchparameter).

A specific limitation of TeamCity email notification (it should be easy to support) is that you can not filter notifications by a *combination* of build configuration and 'Ignore failures not caused by my changes'. Then at least you could configure the build for the main branch so that committers are notified, and create specific settings only for the topic branch projects.

Comment: Although there appears to be no solution to my question, your answer is the closest one to fix the notification problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, I have added another suggestion, writing a custom plug-in, and restructured the answer a bit. In case you go for option 2 I would be interested too... :-)

Answer (score 27):

I'm pretty sure this is the same issue that we had a few days ago, but vice-versa. We merged a dev branch into master, which caused TC to attempt to build each and every check-in that was part of the merge.  Obviously not what we wanted.

To fix it, keep the `Trigger build on each check-in` option unchecked in the `Build Trigger`.

You get the full change history from the source branch, but TeamCity will only build the destination branch using the latest merged code.  If that build fails, the merger should be the only one notified.

Comment: That reads really badly. I was under the impression turning that off would trigger no builds. But I tried it and my double build problem is gone, thanks Jaz.

Comment: I had the exact same thought, the wording could do with looking at there.

Comment: Merged a long-running branch earlier with this option on and Teamcity tried to add 80 builds to the queue! This is definitely a strangely worded option, though definitely deservedly in "Advanced Options".

Answer (score 5):

This is a long shot, and you've probably already tried it, but might it work to apply the `per check-in` trigger option to `Include several check-ins in build if they are from the same committer`?  This might be enough to trick TC into building the commits as a single bundle.