# How do I prevent one merge to develop resulting in multiple builds, one for each commit?

Tags: tfs, teamcity

Using TFS, Git and TeamCity here.

We have a newer solution that a team member recently built out the build chain for. This build chain ignores feature branches. I just did a single commit of my feature to develop but instead of running the commit build once, it ran the commit build three times, once for each commit in my feature.

Do I have to squash my commits in the feature before merging to develop to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I encountered this issue was this feature had multiple committers. TC has the option of modifying the "per check-in" trigger to "include several check-ins in build if they are from the same committer".

Normally we only have one engineer on a feature branch so we had not previously noticed this behavior.

Credit to [@John Hoerr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1453907/john-hoerr) for this [answer from a similar post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876417/how-to-tell-teamcity-to-treat-merges-as-a-single-commit-when-working-with-git)

Comment: Great to see your issue is solved. Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) once you can, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.